# How can I make this fog more dense in the middle?

Tags: materials, volumetrics

I want to have the legs gradually disappear into the fog so how can I make the fog denser in the middle?

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a *Gradient* (in *Quadratic Sphere* or *Spherical* mode) as factor in a *Principled Volume* or *Volume Scatter* node. Here I've used 2 cubes, one bigger, one smaller, to make the volume scatter effect denser:

[image]

Or as Gordon says, use a *Gradient Texture, Linear* type:

[image]

Comment: Especially with a clear direction to where the fog should be more dense like shown in the screenshot, a linear gradient could be useful too.

Comment: oh yes of course

Comment: Thank you, with some tweaking I was able to get it

Comment: @Elven_Randomness: Hi Elven, if the answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of the answer. thank you.